# Problem while starting Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

i am using WebSphere development studio that is eclipse while starting i am facing following problem..[image]

kindly help how to resolve the problem...[image]

this the target value of my shortcut which i am using..
"E:\Program Files\IBM\SDP70\eclipse.exe" -product com.ibm.etools.iseries.wdsc.welcome.ide

Comment: I solved my problem by replacing JDK thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add non jvm options after the jvm options. In your case you have `-jar E:\Program Files\IBM\...`

Move this before `-vmargs` and it should work.

Comment: @Tarlog this is content of my eclipse configuration file..
-vm
E:\Program Files\IBM\SDP70\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xquickstart
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:singleJVM,keep
-Xnolinenumbers
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
So where i need to change

Comment: @Tarlog in which file i need to change?

Comment: Please add eclipse.ini and a shortcut you use to run Eclipse to your question, so it would be formatted and easier to see.

Comment: Basically it should be either in eclipse.ini or in a shortcut/command-line you use to run eclipse.

Comment: I added ini file kindly check

Comment: Do you use any special shortcut?

Comment: just normal eclipse shortcut i am using

Comment: When you say normal it means no arguments? Or may be it contains some?

Comment: you see, this -jar thing must come from somewhere, if it is not in the ini file, it must be in a shortcut...

Comment: I understand, can you also copy+paste the shortcut your are using?

Comment: yes you are correct i am also thinking that one how can i see this file??

Comment: You are at Windows, right? So right click on the shortcut you are using and select properties.

Comment: i added that shortcut.. refer the arrow

Comment: No-o-o-o. Right-click it, select properties, select Target and copy+paste the value.

Comment: I hardly believe that it's all. It must at least include the eclipse.exe file

Comment: to select + copy+paste the whole line

Comment: "E:\Program Files\IBM\SDP70\eclipse.exe" -product com.ibm.etools.iseries.wdsc.welcome.ide

Comment: Hmmmm, do you have ECLIPSE_HOME system variable defined?

Comment: i am not defined any ECLIPSE_HOME variable